# var/system/journal logs flooded with i2c_hid i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (14/65535)

Tags: kernel, touchpad, syslog, logging

So for the last day or two, DiskUsage keeps complaining about no disk space on my root `/` partition.

I can mitigate this issue by editing the `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` and setting the `SystemMaxUse=200M` and then restarting the `journald` by running `sudo service systemd-journald restart`.

However, I'd like to get to the root issue of this because the following line is continually dumped into my logs for some reason:

`Sep 22 08:05:51 aaron kernel: [12884.056854] i2c_hid i2c-ELAN0712:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (14/65535)`

This is happening several times a second constantly. I've seen other people with `/var/log` issues with a very similar set of log entries.

this is what I get when I run `tail /var/log/syslog`:

```
Sep 22 08:07:41 aaron kernel: [12994.605768] i2c_hid i2c-ELAN0712:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (14/65535)
Sep 22 08:07:41 aaron kernel: [12994.606427] i2c_hid i2c-ELAN0712:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (14/65535)
Sep 22 08:07:41 aaron kernel: [12994.607156] i2c_hid i2c-ELAN0712:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (14/65535)
Sep 22 08:07:41 aaron kernel: [12994.607775] i2c_hid i2c-ELAN0712:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (14/65535)
Sep 22 08:07:41 aaron kernel: [12994.608391] i2c_hid i2c-ELAN0712:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (14/65535)
Sep 22 08:07:41 aaron kernel: [12994.609035] i2c_hid i2c-ELAN0712:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (14/65535)
Sep 22 08:07:41 aaron kernel: [12994.609752] i2c_hid i2c-ELAN0712:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (14/65535)
Sep 22 08:07:41 aaron kernel: [12994.610382] i2c_hid i2c-ELAN0712:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (14/65535)
Sep 22 08:07:41 aaron kernel: [12994.611008] i2c_hid i2c-ELAN0712:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (14/65535)
Sep 22 08:07:41 aaron kernel: [12994.611654] i2c_hid i2c-ELAN0712:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (14/65535)
```

It was 7:41am when I ran that command so this is happening constantly.

What's going on? How can I fix the issue that's causing this constant logging?

**EDIT:**
So it looks like this might have something to do with my touchpage (This is an HP Laptop) but my mousepad runs just fine. My keyboard is working and my laptop also has a touchscreen feature which is also working.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to follow the solution of Pablo Abrudsky in [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1784152). It worked for me. You'll need to access to `/etc/default/grub` and change
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`
to
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="`
and then run:

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

And finally, vacuum the journal. Good luck!!!